# Cleaning up tags for the .NET Framework Client Profile

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

Earlier today, someone created [.net-4.0-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-client-profile).  Being a new tag deletionist, I swooped in to determine if there was a better, already-existing tag.

I found three others.  Four!  [client-profile](/questions/tagged/client-profile), [clientprofile](/questions/tagged/clientprofile) (had about 20 questions), [client-profile-4](/questions/tagged/client-profile-4) (had about 10 questions), [.net-client-framework](/questions/tagged/.net-client-framework) (had about 8 questions).

Thinking that the newest tag was the *least ambiguous*, I went through all of the other questions and retagged all the questions about the Client Profile for .NET 4 into [.net-4.0-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-client-profile), and moved all the questions about either 3.5 or that weren't version-specific into [client-profile](/questions/tagged/client-profile).

Then BoltClock pointed out that 4.5 is around the corner, which makes the very specific 4.0 tag slightly *too* specific.

Oops.

How should this be fixed?  One catch-all tag?  Given the relatively low volume of questions, it could work.  We probably *don't* need version tags here.  Probably.  If so, should it remain *just* [client-profile](/questions/tagged/client-profile)?  To me, that seems possibly ambiguous.  Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.net-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-client-profile) springs to mind.

BoltClock is right, once .NET 4.5 is released, it makes a version-specific tag such as [.net-4.0-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-client-profile) *too specific* for questions about the .NET client profile *in general*.

With [.net-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-client-profile) it will address all versions of the client profile in .NET.

If there is an issue specific to one version of the client profile in .NET, then I'd say it can be tagged with [.net-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-client-profile) *and* the framework-specific version tag (e.g. [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0), [.net-4.5](/questions/tagged/.net-4.5), etc.)

Comment: Accepting this one because the versioned .net tags make an amazing amount of sense and I disagree with the synonym idea.  Now, who wants to do it?  I could go through *all* of the questions again and edit them, but you guys are moderators and could do it faster...

Comment: @Charles You *did* ask the question....  Just because we are moderators doesn't mean we have super-edit abilities.

Comment: Just checking before getting started.

Comment: @Charles There's also [tag:.net-client-framework] which seems to be synonymous as well.  I'll help retag now.  Once these are done, put up a meta post asking to burninate these four tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm not going to ask for burnination separately, I doubt that the old tags will spring back to life before they're recycled automatically.

Comment: @Charles No worry, I'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [.net-client-profile](/questions/tagged/.net-client-profile), without the version. We already have version tags handy, which users already use when tagging their questions and can use along with it.

I should also think it's safe to make [client-profile](/questions/tagged/client-profile) and [clientprofile](/questions/tagged/clientprofile) synonyms of that, since *so far* there hasn't been any usage of either tag to refer to technologies other than the .NET Framework.

Comment: I'd disagree with making them synonyms; burninate them, as another technology might come along one day where "client profile" is more appropriate, or it might become something that is standardized.